# ¿Cómo llenar un input con los campos de un usuario en la base de datos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, dotnetcore

Estoy intentando actualizar los datos de un usuario en la base de datos utilizando Razor. Para eso llevo los datos a un input para modificarlos. El problema es que me trae todos los elementos que estén en la base de datos y me los manda al frontend, cuando necesito obtenerlos por id.

¿Existe alguna manera de validar mediante un id? o ¿Se puede recorrer un IEnumerable sin usar un bucle for?

**Actualizar.cshtml**

```
@foreach (var mascota in Model.Mascotas)
    {
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label>Nombre </label>        
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@mascota.NombreMascota">
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="inputEspecie">Especie </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@mascota.Especie">            
        </div> 
    }
```

**Actualizar.cshtml.cs**

```
public class ActualizarModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly iRepositorioMascota _RepoMascota;
        public IEnumerable<Mascota> Mascotas { get;set; }
        
        public ActualizarModel(iRepositorioMascota _RepoMascota){
            this._RepoMascota = _RepoMascota;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Mascotas = _RepoMascota.GetAllMascota();
        }
    }
```

En cierta ocasión vi usar el anchor tag helper para este fin, sin embargo, no logro encontrar algo relacionado.

Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el ejemplo de la mascota, y ya que veo que estas empeznado con Razor Pages te mencionare algunas cosas, este te permite recibir los argumentos desde la URL de la página o de un campo del formulario, a través de un "Binding" automático, pero para CADA operación REST (Get, Post, Delete, etc). Si tienes en tu HTML un formulario POST recuerda que debes colocar dos metodos. Adicionalmente por desempeño recuerda aprovechar las operaciones asincronas (async).

Existen dos formas de recibir los argumentos desde la URL: /mascota/actualizar?id=1

1. Bind a Propiedad del modelo, hay que indicarle que estas pueden ser recibidas en la propiedad y si lo soportará en el método GET. Ventaja es que si viene de la URL lo tienes en todos las operaciones REST. Podrás notar que en la URL ejemplo está todo en minusculas, y en la propiedad la primer letra es mayúscula, el binding no hace distinciones.

```
public class ActualizarModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly iRepositorioMascota _RepoMascota;
    public IEnumerable<Mascota> Mascotas { get;set; }
        
    public ActualizarModel(iRepositorioMascota _RepoMascota){
        this._RepoMascota = _RepoMascota;
    }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Mascotas = _RepoMascota.GetMascota(Id);
    }
}
```

2. Bind a parametros del método, por defecto lo extraera del 'Query String'

```
public void OnGet(int id)
{
    Mascotas = _RepoMascota.GetMascota(id);
}
```

Si prefieres que el ID del registro sea parte de la direcció (/mascota/actualizar/1) deberás modificar del markup de razor en el .cshtml, para indicarle el formato del url en la línea de page

```
@page "{id}"
```

Si fuese solo una mascota por usuario podrías omitir lo anterior, pero entonces tu consulta es la que debe recibir el nombre del usuario y buscar su registro relacionado para obtener el ID, primero deberás tener al usuario autenticado, y esto depende de como está configurada la seguridad de tu aplicación, si es con cookies, con Tokens y Claims, etc. En general para extraer el nombre de usuario lo encontrarás en "HttpContext.User.Identity.Name", HttpContext es una propiedad de PageModel, e idealmente pasar este nombre o el ID correspondiente hasta la operación de lógica de negocio, para que el registro sea validado al mismo tiempo que pertenece a este usuario, cuando ya estes grabando el registro. Si la autenticacón es diferente como Tokens con Claims podrías tener ahí mismo el ID.

Comment: Gracias por tan detallada respuesta. Me aclaró muchos de los conceptos que estaba considerando. Efectivamente el cosa actual corresponde a la última parte del comentario, una mascota pertenece a un sólo usuario y al acceder a la página de actualización de usuario este puede acceder a sus datos y los de mascota. ¿Es posible utilizar bind bajo este esquema? Hasta el momento no he definido la autenticación.

Comment: O por el contrario, ¿conoce algún recurso informativo para integrar Identity a la arquitectura por capas que estoy usando

Comment: No se puede utilizar bind para lo que planteas. Tienes que obtener el nombre del usuario con:

HttpContext.User.Identity.Name

Luego podes usar IdentityUser para saber cual es el ID del usuario. Tendrías que solicitar el servicio de 'UserManager<IdentityUser>" y usar el método 'GetUserByName(string)', te devolverá el 'IdentityUser' y de esto ya usas la propiedad 'Id'.

Es mejor descubrir este dato en el PageModel, que integrarlo a tu lógica de capa media, por que tendrías que usar el IHttpContextAccessor para poder usar el HttpContext y te lo cohesiona con la capa de presentación.